# He was still on a natural high after cheating death. (what's the meaning of the sentence?)

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> He was still on a natural high after cheating death.

https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/enko/874be27d244b4541bb6f0a26bac38c02 [adjective]

I understand the expression 'be on a natural/real/... high' but can't understand the meaning of the full sentence.

I know all the words but the sentence meaning is obscured.

Comment: Cheating death means narrowly escaping death. You may feel great afterwards.

Comment: Is this word 'cheating death' used a lot? I can't even look for the word in a dictionary.

Comment: You can just try searching Google for it, like "what does cheating death mean".  It doesn't always work, but it can be a good starting point.

Comment: 'Cheating death' is a very common expression.

Comment: In a dictionary, it might be listed as "cheat death" or "(to) cheat death", since "cheat**ing**" is the participle form. Or it might be listed as an idiomatic phrase under the "cheat" or "death" definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's meaning that the person was experiencing an endorphin or adrenaline spike as if drugged after having a close brush with death. Think of something like being on a high-speed road and suddenly the tire comes off the vehicle in front of you and smashes into your car (this is something that actually happened to me once, I was shaking for minutes afterward). It totally wrecked the grill and front hood as well as leaving a small dent in the roof.

Comment: **Its meaning is that....** or **It means that**. NOT **It's meaning that the....**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion. Use a Google search, with quotes, and the word 'meaning'. Then look for links to dictionary sites.

[image]

Comment: The search `dictionary definition "cheat death"` produced good results for me.

Comment: @MJ713 - likewise `"cheat death" meaning dictionary` - 5 different dictionaries at the top of the results.